# Genymotion requires VirtualBox to be installed on your computer

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

[image]

How do I fix this error? The latest version of the software is installed

Comment: I inlined your image and improved your question title. What part of this message is unclear? "Genymotion requires VirtualBox to be installed on your computer", followed by a link where you can download it seems pretty clear.

Comment: Any fix for this ? I updated my genymotion and virtual box and this annoying error keeps me from using it. Darn. Any help ?

Comment: yes,after install all tools,then i encountered the same problem when i directly open genymotion.but reboot pc helps.

Answer (score -3):

Do u run it in Windows 10?
If yes, That is because of Oracle VM VirtualBox is not support Windows 10 yet. I tried with the same steps in win7x64 machine, it works fine.